# Fundamental question for monero: how to mine myself

Tags: blockchain

Let's assume 2 people (Person A and Person B) are mining.
Person A finds a block 2 seconds before person B. Each of them is mining at home on their own.
What should person A do to claim his block or, in other words, where does he register it?

Answer (score 1):

When Alice finds a block, she will send it to the Monero nodes she's connected to. In turn, these nodes will (assuming the block is valid when they verify it) will send it to the nodes they're connected to, etc.

When Bob finds a block two seconds later, the same will happen, but Bob and Alice are likely connected to a different set of nodes.

What will then happen is that Alice's block will propagate through the network of nodes, and Bob's will too, a little bit later. Alice will have some head start, and will reach more nodes quicker than Bob's.

If a block receives Bob's block, but already has received Alice's, that node will reject Bob's block (assuming it does not have a higher cumulative difficulty than Alice's, which is the usual case). That node will then not send Bob's block any further.

You then end up with some part of the network having a blockchain with Alice's block at its tip, and another part of the network having Bob's. The network is forked. Alice had a head start of two seconds, so most of the network probably has Alice's block, and is now mining for a block over it. The other part of the network is now mining a block on top of Bob's block.

The next miner to find a block (either on top of Alice's or Bob's) will send it to the nodes it's connected to, again. Let's assuming it's Alice's. Miners who are still mining on top of Bob's block will get see a valid incoming block with a higher cumulative difficulty than their current tip, and will remove Bob's block from their blockchain and replace it with Alice's and the new one.

So there is no central registration authority. Every node keeps its own version of the blockchain, and uses cumulative difficulty to decide which to keep. Cumulative difficulty is based on the difficulty of all blocks in the chain.

Comment: excellent thank you .. It is still unclear to me, as far as i learned I know how to connect to a pool, but i don't know how to connect to a node for self mining.

Comment: You just run monerod, and it will automatically find the Monero network and connect to other nodes.

Comment: When i read more about the protocol used? i find this point unclear, because the submit does not have the wallet as a parameters. How does the monerod know this is Alex or Bob?

Comment: When you start mining, you give monerod the wallet address to mine to.

Comment: I managed to setup a pool, and run monerod in the background. And run the cpuminer to the pool and the pool sends to the monerod. But i get many times transaction failed? does this mean that for mining, we need to run the wallet in the background?